# Images and Widgets don't appear in html after converting Jupyter notebook - Python

Tags: python, html, pdf, jupyter-notebook, nbconvert

I'm using Jupyter notebook to write up my report using Markdown and Python to make widgets.
On the Jupyter notebook, when I click on "file", then "Download as" HTML(.html), it converts my notebook.

In the html, I noticed that none of my widgets appear, and any images I've attached by markdown as `<img src="myimagehere.png">` also disappear.

Only the actual code, " appears, not the image itself.

P.S. I also just noticed that the markdown mathematical notation like Latex suddenly appears as only code in html. So three problems in one, wonderful.

Been struggling to find an answer/solution. Can anyone please help? Many thanks.

Comment: Any solution on this. I have a relatively close issue. I lose the image when I attach the rendered html with the image into an outlook email. The image it is displayed perfect before I attach the file though.